# DataGrid: How to remove black inner borders?

Tags: wpf

I have a datagrid:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gvImports" 
    HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    Margin="10,36.816,0,0" 
    VerticalAlignment="Top" 
    Height="163.087" Width="485.05">
</DataGrid>
```

Then I am setting the cell border style in C#:

```
var cellStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));
cellStyle.Setters.Add
      (new Setter(DataGridCell.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.Magenta));
gvImports.CellStyle = cellStyle;
```

Notice the offensive Magenta for demonstration purposes only.

Here is an image of the DataGrid when rendered:

[image]

I want to get rid of those inner black lines, any idea how this is done?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
gvImports.GridLinesVisibility = DataGridGridLinesVisibility.None;
```

Answer (score 2):

Set the horizontal and vertical grid line brushes ([HorizontalGridLinesBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.horizontalgridlinesbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [VerticalGridLinesBrush](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.verticalgridlinesbrush%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). See [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2009/01/20/styling-microsoft-s-wpf-datagrid.aspx) for a list of data grid styling properties.